# Center TextView below FrameLayout

Tags: android, xml

So I have a FrameLayout with an Image View and a Progressbar. And below the frame layout I have a textview. How do I center this textview below the image/framelayout properly. Here is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lodr9.jpg, and here is what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxI6R.jpg

With this, the text is centered, but now the progressbar doesn't display while the image loads:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="?attr/background"
    tools:context="com.nmoorthy.malscoretracker.ViewAnimeScores">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/text_color_inverse"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/innerrelativelayout"
        >
        <!--<FrameLayout-->
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:id="@+id/image"
                />

        <!--</FrameLayout>-->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:text="Status"
            android:id="@+id/status"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Synopsis"
        android:id="@+id/synopsis"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/innerrelativelayout"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="18.9dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/innerrelativelayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:maxLines="6"
        android:ellipsize="end" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="10.0"
        android:id="@+id/highScore"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="13dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/innerrelativelayout"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0.0"
        android:id="@+id/lowScore"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="77dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:layout_below="@+id/innerrelativelayout"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/noGraph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:paddingTop="40dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@id/innerrelativelayout"
        android:text="You need at least 2 scores for a graph"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <com.db.chart.view.LineChartView
        android:id="@+id/linechart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/highScore"
        android:layout_below="@+id/innerrelativelayout"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4/8/16"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lowScore"
        android:layout_below="@id/linechart"
        android:id="@+id/firstdate"
        />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/firstdate"
        android:layout_below="@id/linechart">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="4/13/16"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/lastdate"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="3dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstdate"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to center status under the imageview in frame. I've tried center horizontal and alignparentbottom but they both don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on the **TextView**.

I suppose you are applying gravity as center_horizontal which will only center **content** of TextView inside TextView - which is an alternative solution if you were using `match_parent` on your TextView.

EDIT : Based on your comment on other answer, it seems you are downloading the image dynamically. So when view is drawn, parent width is the width of **ProgressBar**, and the TextView centers itself accordingly. When the image is loaded, you need to call `requestLayout()` on the parent RelativeLayout to measure and re-layout the TextView with the new width.

Comment: I have already tried that and they don't work. I already have the width to match_parent as well.

Comment: Try calling requestLayout() and invalidate() on your parent RelativeLayout (which contains FrameLayout and TextView) - AFTER the image is downloaded and set in the ImageView.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to have worked either unfortunately. I tried it with  have centerHorizontal and alignparentbottom and using match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. 
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html

and you are putting two layouts inside FrameLayout.  Let's use RelativeLayout and alignparentbottom set to true.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the FrameLayout to show a progressbar in place of  an image until it is loaded.

Comment: I need the FrameLayout because of that so I shouldn't remove it.

Comment: did you try layout_gravity and gravity ?

Comment: Can you post you entire layout ? I will check what's wrong there.

Comment: Its quite problematic. Use RelativeLayout instead and align those with it.

Comment: That just doesn't seem viable because I want to have the progressbar in place of the image when it's loading.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to get it right without the frame layout and using centerHorizontal and moving the framelayout margins to the inner relativelayout. Wait, now the progressbar isn't showing...

Comment: Can you update your question, so others can use it ?

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
<ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"   // Changes here
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/image"
            />

    <!--</FrameLayout>-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"   // Changes here 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"    
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:text="Status"
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

in Textview,layout_below,give id of the frame layout,if you want to your view to be below it